# Write a function named WeekDay() making use of select case, the function will receive a single argument containing a STRING (days Monday - Sunday)

Tags: string, return, arguments, case, scilab

Use Scilab answer the following questions:
Paste both your function code, and console output demonstrating the features of the function.
Write a function named WeekDay() making use of select case, the function will receive a single argument containing  a STRING (days Monday - Sunday) and print a corresponding number and return an integer which is the matching week day name based on the following pairing:
1 : Monday
2 : Tuesday
3 : Wednesday
4 : Thursday
5 : Friday
6 : Saturday
7: Sunday
The function will also give the same result regardless of case of the argument string (i.e. Monday, and Monday and MONDAY will all be treated equally).
Sample output:
--> WeekDay('Tuesday')
ans  =
2

I am unable to solve it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **We won’t do your work for you.** Copy/pasting your homework into the text area thinking someone will do it for you is not only cheating, but will hurt you in the long run, as you probably won’t perform well on future assignments/tests. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then [edit] to include past attempts and a [mre] showing what you have completed so far. For more info, check out the [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166) and [this Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/20153035).

Answer (score 0):

WeekDay() is a function it will accept one parameter as Date and it returns weekday value.

You can try something like this.
SELECT case WEEKDAY(NOW())
when 'Monday' then 1
when 'Tuesday' then 2
when 'Wednesday' then 3
when 'Thursday' then 4
when 'Friday' then 5
when 'Saturday' then 6
when 'Sunday' then
END